# Send byte[] continuously from server to client?

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

I'm pretty new to this, I just want to send a message from my console server window to the client.

Here's my server:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
                Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                newsock.Bind(localEndPoint);
                newsock.Listen(10);
                Socket client = newsock.Accept();

                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("client connected.");
                }

                string msg = "Who's there?";
                byte[] buffer = new byte[msg.Count()];
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                client.Send(buffer);
```

It works fine when i use client.Send() above, but when when I do as follows below I receive nothing on the other end. Since the client is connected, I see no reason why it fails.

```
                    while (client.Connected)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("enter msg: ");
                        string userMsg = Console.ReadLine();
                        byte[] userBuffer = new byte[userMsg.Count()];
                        userBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userMsg);
                        client.Send(userBuffer);

                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
            }    
    }
```

Here's the code for the client:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                          SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8000);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[12];


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                          SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Connect(ipep);

        if (server.Connected)
        {
            txt_Log.AppendText("\nConnected to target server.");
        }


        btn.IsEnabled = false;
        btn_disc.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void btn_Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        server.Close();

        if (!server.Connected)
        {
            txt_Log.AppendText("\nDisconnected to target server.");
        }
        btn.IsEnabled = true;
        btn_disc.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btn_Fetch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            using (server)
            {
                server.Receive(buffer);
                txt_Log.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
                buffer = null;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            txt_Log.AppendText("\nNo data to send.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens in your `btn_Fetch_Click` ? Does it write "No data to send." ? or...? Note: the receive code is horribly horribly broken; TCP data is typically a stream - you don't always "receive" things in the nice convenient chunks in which they were sent; you should be checking the return value of `Receive`, which tells you the number of bytes it read (this does not need to be an entire message; it could be a single byte, it could be 27 messages)

Comment: also: do you have `NoDelay` enabled on the socket?

Comment: Please read a TCP socket tutorial. Some common mistakes here.

Comment: @MarcGravell What I'm trying to do is that every time I press "Fetch", the client will receive any data the server wants to send. Nope, no NoDelay anywhere. :)

Comment: @usr Sorry, I've read plenty but this is how far I got in my understanding.

Comment: "the client will receive any data the server wants to send" - no; the server sends whenever it wants to; you don't "fetch" from a socket; you can, however, look at what was already received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've run your server code. No problems there...

For the client, it seemed you dispose the server, which drops the connnection? and null the buffer, so you can't re-use that either....

I wrote some test client code which seemed to work fine

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            int bytes = server.Receive(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the point of this you don't disconnect the client every time you read a packet, and if you null your static before and then null check **it is going to be null** so fetch will only work once, therefore don't do it!
Also as Mark said, check the number of bytes read from the call the Receive so you can tell how many bytes to decode.

Comment: Connection refused when I test your code. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Connection refused

Comment: @BohaoLI I would guess that either the server isn't running, is running on a different port, is running on a different machine or you have a firewall in the way

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
private void btn_Fetch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        using (server)
        {
            server.Receive(buffer);
            txt_Log.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
            buffer = null;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        txt_Log.AppendText("\nNo data to send.");
    }
}
```

To..

```
private void btn_Fetch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        server.Receive(buffer);
        txt_Log.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
        buffer = null;
    }
    else
    {
        txt_Log.AppendText("\nNo data to send.");
    }
}
```

and call dispose when the window is closed

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnClosed(e);
    server.Dispose();
}
```